# JavaScript / Constructor Functions

Tags: javascript

I'm still learning JavaScript. Not able to get past this:

```
  function Fruits(category, berries, notberries) {
      this.category = category;
      this.berries = [];
      this.notberries = [];
  }

  let f = new Fruits("fresh", ["strawberry", "raspberry"], ["apple", "mango"]);

  console.log(f); // Fruits {category: "fresh", berries: Array(0), notberries: Array(0)}

  f.category;  //"fresh"

  f.berries; //[]
```

Why is it not logging the values of berries and instead returning an empty array ?

Comment: By calling `this.berries = [];` you've declared `berries`' value as an empty array, regardless of the constructor's parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the arguments to the proper attributes.

```js
function Fruits(category, berries, notberries) {
  this.category = category;
  this.berries = berries;
  this.notberries = notberries;
}

let f = new Fruits("fresh", ["strawberry", "raspberry"], ["apple", "mango"]);

console.log(f); // Fruits {category: "fresh", berries: Array(0), 
f.category;
f.berries;
```

Comment: Which local variables? The parameters *are* local variables.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in your constructor ever assigns the parameter `berries` to the property `this.berries` (or copies its content); the same for `notberries`.

To assign:

```
function Fruits(category,berries,notberries) {
    this.category = category;
    this.berries = berries;          // ***
    this.notberries = notberries;    // ***
}
```

To copy (shallow, which is fine, these are arrays of strings):

```
function Fruits(category,berries,notberries) {
    this.category = category;
    this.berries = berries.slice();          // ***
    this.notberries = notberries.slice();    // ***
}
```

The difference is that if you *assign*, then the object has a reference to the array that was passed in, and so does the calling code; if the calling code modifies that array, it affects the object (since they share the array). If you *copy* the contents of the array, then the calling code and the object each have their own array, so changes to one don't affect the other.

Both can be correct, you just need to be aware of the distinction.